# GSA search manipulate - change search keywords

Tags: google-search-appliance

IN our GSA, we want to manipulate the keywords sent from the front-end towards the GSA. Is it possible to forward the request to an external app, which will exclude some keywords or enrich the query, and then from there forward to the GSA?

Or maybe is there a way to write some code logic in the Front-End in order to modify the keywords before they are entered as input to the GSA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom portal or application from where you talk to GSA then you can very well get the user query, call an external application, manipulate your query, bring it back to the application, then fire the query to GSA. Once you submit to the frontend, there is no known way to manipulate the query. Custom Query processing does not exsit, afasik but pre-processing, should be possible by many means.

If you are using the default frontend then you sure can call a javascript method from XSLT to change your query and then submit request to GSA